# Spring auto configuration for @ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm writting custom starter for global exception handler class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`. I can't put this class into configuration class without need of abstract class, but I've seen example where you leave exception handler in it's own class and put it into `spring.factories` file, but I don't understand how does spring picks it up since in spring docs it is mentioned that `spring.factories` should contain classes annotated with `@Configuration`?

Example here:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(annotation = [ControllerAdvice::class])
class ExceptionHandler {
  ...
}
```

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  test.configuration.controller.ExceptionHandler
```

Does it actually work because of this: `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(annotation = [ControllerAdvice::class])` and adding it to factories is redundant?